# Inconsistent view in simulator vs device

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making an app of a calculator and I put a lot of buttons to the main view. However, when I test it on a simulator, some of the buttons don't show up correctly. Can anyone tell me what happens? I'm totally confused because I just drag buttons, labels, etc. from the toolbox in the right of the XCode and changed their fonts and aligned them to role and columns. I didn't do any programming things to buttons (except for adding `IBActions` and `Outlets`). Here is a snapshot of my problem.

[image: snapshot]

By the way, the colored rectangles are just textfields to store expressions and answers. They will be transparent finally and are currently colored to show positions on the screen for convenience.

I can't give more details because I don't know anything about any possible reasons. After all, designing the view is just a drawing and aesthetic issue but I am stuck now. Can anyone give an explanation?

Comment: problem in second row button ?

Comment: In snapshot we see all the buttons. Which buttons are you talking about?

Comment: I guess ^2 and History

Comment: If you are using autolayout disable it

Comment: @Rushabh Yes, all the second row buttons are not shown correctly.

Comment: @Rushi the left is storyboard and the right is simulator. You can see that the texts on the second row buttons are "erased".

Comment: Are you settings the text of the buttons in runtime? It seems to me that the text is being set at runtime and it's too large to fit, so the AutoSize button option kicks in and decreases font size...

Comment: Delete the second row of buttons, then copy the first row and past it there. Adjust properties as you see fit :)

Comment: @zyl1024: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I need to disable `autolayout`. With `autolayout`, I guess that XCode will optimize with `autolayout` option on. After turning it off, everything looks good.

Comment: You really should be using AutoLayout to account for different screen sizes